# Discord.js playing a sound leaving and join after x time and do the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am new to programming with JS and wanted to make something for fun. I have created a discord bot which joins a server after messaging burp and plays a burp sound and then leaves the discord again. Now what I really want it to do is that it plays a burp leaves and after x minutes connect again and do another burp.

I am not sure how to start and if this is possible. I imagine that I have to make a list with the multiple burps and let the bot loop through that but the join after 10 minutes is something I cannot figure out.

Current code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var isReady = true;

const prefix = '-';
const token = 'INSERT TOKEN HERE';

bot.on('message', message => {
  if (isReady && message.content === 'Burp')
  {
  isReady = false;
  var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
  message.member.voice.channel.join().then(connection =>
  {
    const dispatcher = connection.play('./audio/burp.wav');
    dispatcher.on("finish", finish => {
        connection.disconnect();
       });
   }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   isReady = true;
  }
});

bot.login(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();
var isReady = true;

const prefix = '-';
const token = 'INSERT TOKEN HERE';

bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'Burp'){
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
// setInterval repeats the function after a given amount of Milliseconds
    setInterval(function() { 
      voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => {
           connection.play("./audio/burp.wav")
              .on("finish", () => connection.disconnect())
                });
     }, 600000) //10 Minutes in Milliseconds = 600000
}) 

bot.login(token)
```

See [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) in the MDN Docs.

Comment: Please explain why this is a solution. What does your solution do, how does it solve the problem.(It should also have an educational effect on people who find this question because they have a similar problem. )

Comment: Forgot to add the comments - Thanks Max!